# JS, Promise и глобальные переменные

Tags: javascript

Нужно загрузить данные из текстового файла в глобальную переменную.

```
var value = '';
fetch('url')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
       value = data  
    });
```

Знаю что в Promise с данными можно работать только так

```
.then(data => {
    // код 
});
```

Но нужно именно вывести данные в глобальную переменную.

```
var value = "";

$.ajax({
    url: txt,
    type: 'get',
    success: function(data) {
        var twig = String(data);
        value = value.concat(twig);
    }
});
```

Так тоже значение value меняется только внутри функции

Comment: В первом блоке кода, ты вполне себе сохраняешь результат в глобальную переменную.

Comment: `value.concat(twig);` - в этом куске кода значение самой переменной `value` Не меняется, и результат `concat` - присваивается в никуда

Comment: @Grundy `В первом блоке кода, ты вполне себе сохраняешь результат` вы уверены? как-то в console.log(value) выводит не то, что ожидалось увидеть, точнее там пустая строка

Comment: @Grundy `в этом куске кода значение самой переменной...` исправил, тоже самое

Comment: _вы уверены?_ - мы уверены. Просто ты вызываешь `console.log` **до того** как запрос завершится и значение присвоится. Чтобы дождаться завершение запроса - смотри ответы в дубликате.